# LNK2005 error between cpp file and cu file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, caffe

I am building dll for [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) library with Visual Studio 2013. I have Link error 2005, I guess a conflict between `flatten_layer.cpp` and `flatten_layer.cu`.
The errors are

```
1>flatten_layer.obj : error LNK2005: "char caffe::gInstantiationGuardFlattenLayer" (?gInstantiationGuardFlattenLayer@caffe@@3DA) already defined in flatten_layer.cu.obj
1>.\bin\caffe.dll : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

This `gInstantiationGuardFlattenLayer` is not in both `flatten_layer.cpp` and `flatten_layer.cu`. Why this Linker error is there? I use Visual Studio 2013 to compile.

My `flatten_layer.cpp` and `flatten_layer.cu` are as follows.

flatten_layer.cpp

```
#include <vector>

#include "caffe/layer.hpp"
#include "caffe/util/math_functions.hpp"
#include "caffe/vision_layers.hpp"

namespace caffe {

template <typename Dtype>
void FlattenLayer<Dtype>::Reshape(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom,
      const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {
  const int start_axis = bottom[0]->CanonicalAxisIndex(
      this->layer_param_.flatten_param().axis());
  const int end_axis = bottom[0]->CanonicalAxisIndex(
      this->layer_param_.flatten_param().end_axis());
  vector<int> top_shape;
  for (int i = 0; i < start_axis; ++i) {
    top_shape.push_back(bottom[0]->shape(i));
  }
  const int flattened_dim = bottom[0]->count(start_axis, end_axis + 1);
  top_shape.push_back(flattened_dim);
  for (int i = end_axis + 1; i < bottom[0]->num_axes(); ++i) {
    top_shape.push_back(bottom[0]->shape(i));
  }
  top[0]->Reshape(top_shape);
  CHECK_EQ(top[0]->count(), bottom[0]->count());
}

template <typename Dtype>
void FlattenLayer<Dtype>::Forward_cpu(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom,
      const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {
  top[0]->ShareData(*bottom[0]);
}

template <typename Dtype>
void FlattenLayer<Dtype>::Backward_cpu(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top,
      const vector<bool>& propagate_down, const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom) {
  bottom[0]->ShareDiff(*top[0]);
}

INSTANTIATE_CLASS(FlattenLayer);
REGISTER_LAYER_CLASS(Flatten);

}  // namespace caffe
```

flatten_layer.cu

```
#include <vector>

#include "caffe/layer.hpp"
#include "caffe/util/math_functions.hpp"
#include "caffe/vision_layers.hpp"

namespace caffe {

template <typename Dtype>
void FlattenLayer<Dtype>::Forward_gpu(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom,
      vector<Blob<Dtype>*>* top) {
  (*top)[0]->ShareData(*bottom[0]);
}

template <typename Dtype>
void FlattenLayer<Dtype>::Backward_gpu(const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top,
      const vector<bool>& propagate_down, vector<Blob<Dtype>*>* bottom) {
  (*bottom)[0]->ShareDiff(*top[0]);
}

INSTANTIATE_CLASS(FlattenLayer);

}  // namespace caffe
```

Comment: I don't use caffe but the fact you have `INSTANTIATE_CLASS(FlattenLayer);` in both files raises a red flag with me.

Comment: Yeah good point. I checked and normally those .cu files has INSTANTIATE_LAYER_GPU_FUNCS() at the end of the code. But that particular FlattenLayer.cu file has error to put INSTANTIATE_LAYER_GPU_FUNCS(FlattenLayer). So INSTANTIATE_CLASS(FlattenLayer); is there at end of FlattenLayer.cu. If I comment out INSTANTIATE_CLASS(FlattenLayer); from flatten_layer.cpp, what could be consequences?

Comment: I can't say as caffe/cuda are not something I know enough about.